# How to disable phonon?

Tags: pyside, phonon

How do you disable phonon in PySide?

I am trying to use QWebpage and I don't want phonon to kick in, as the app I'm writing is a server side app, and has no need for media. I tried a few things but did not find any really relevant documentation.

Answer (score 1):

A. If you use Debian/Ubuntu, remove those modules that you don't want

```
sudo apt-get remove python-pyside.phonon
```

http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?mode=exactfilename&suite=oneiric&section=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=pyside

http://www.pyside.org/docs/pyside/contents.html

B.If you use setup.py package your app, you could add a `excludes` option

something looks like this

```
py2app_options = {
    ....
    "excludes" : ["PySide.phonon"],
    ....
    }
```

http://svn.pythonmac.org/py2app/py2app/trunk/doc/index.html#option-reference